# Firefox overflow bug with css background and rounded borders

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, rounded-corners

I'm trying to design a button with orange background and rounded borders but the problem is background overflows. I cant see any problem on Chrome.

I used `overflow: hidden` but no help. Have any idea?

Here is the code:

```
display: inline-block;
padding: 8px 15px 6px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
color: #1f2b20;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #e3bf8b;
font-size: 14px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 3px solid #2e2e2e;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
```

Firefox 
[image: overflow problem] [image: overflow]

Chrome [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want to use in Firefox [is `background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-clip):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
background: linear-gradient(#f8cc55, #ba701d);
color: #1f2b20;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #e3bf8b;
font-size: 14px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 3px solid #2e2e2e;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
background-clip: padding-box;
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Ewccm/).  Remember the `background` property will reset values for any of the sub-properties not specified, so put `background-clip` last.

Answer (score 0):

If the `box-shadow` is not mandatory, remove it. That will fix the issue :)